# Unity: Moving player using Rigidbody with UI Buttons?

Tags: unity, rigidbody

i have been using `transform.position`since the start but now i want to switch to rigidbody instead since i am facing some collision problems. i can use the keyboard to move the player using this code:

```
input = new Vector3 (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));  

        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity.magnitude < maxmovespeed) {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce (input * movespeed);
        }
```

but since i am building for mobile and have added UI buttons for right/left on screen, i wish to use those for moving my player. how can i use those buttons to move in that specific direction like left for left only and right for right?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to move left and right, you could try something like this:

```
if (GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity.magnitude < maxmovespeed) {
    if (leftButton.IsPressed()) {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce (-Vector3.right * movespeed);
    } else if (rightButton.IsPressed()) {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce (Vector3.right * movespeed);
    }
}
```

Just assign leftButton and rightButton as public variables in the editor.

Comment: how can i assign them as public variables?

Comment: Add instance fields in the script, like "public UnityEngine.UI.Button leftButton", then in the editor drag and drop the UI element onto that variable.

Answer (score 0):

We use two Event triggers and Delegate for one is Left side button and second is Right side button.

```
public class EventManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void OnMoveLeft ();
    public static event OnMoveLeft onMoveLeft;
    public static void RaiseOnMoveLeft ()
    {
        if (onMoveLeft != null)
            onMoveLeft ();
    }

    public delegate void OnMoveRight ();
    public static event OnMoveRight onMoveRight;
    public static void RaiseOnMoveRight ()
    {
        if (onMoveRight != null)
            onMoveRight ();
    }
}
```

When UI button clicked, same time event must raise either Left Side or Right Side.

```
public class GamePlayView : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void OnLeft(){
        EventManager.RaiseOnMoveLeft();
    }

    public void OnRight(){
        EventManager.RaiseOnMoveRight();
    }
}
```

Player Script We have to use Event Register and Deregister for Both Event triggers. When Button click that time according to that Event handlers method are called. And player performed.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float forwardSpeed;
    private Rigidbody rigidbody;

    void Awake(){
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void OnEnable(){
        EventManager.onMoveLeft += EventManager_onMoveLeft;
        EventManager.onMoveRight += EventManager_onMoveRight;
    }

    void OnDisable(){
        EventManager.onMoveLeft -= EventManager_onMoveLeft;
        EventManager.onMoveRight -= EventManager_onMoveRight;
    }

    void EventManager_onMoveLeft ()
    {
        rigidbody.AddForce(-Vector3.right * forwardSpeed);
    }

    void EventManager_onMoveRight ()
    {
        rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.right * forwardSpeed);
    }
}
```